# Send Post request with mongoose and nested data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I use NextJS 13 and mongoose. I send POST request with nested data, but for some reasons I can not create `messages` field with nested objects. I can not figured out where I make a mistake

My POST request:

```
{
    "userEmail": "test@gmail.com",
    "level": "3",
    "messages": [{"content":"What is your name?\n","role":"user","createdAt":"2023-10-26T18:30:11.460Z","id":"akNgQwb"},{"id":"I61VGsq","createdAt":"2023-10-26T18:30:12.605Z","content":"My name is Jack.","role":"assistant"}]
}
```

But the `message` field wasn't created and response looks like this:

```
{
    "userEmail": "test@gmail.com",
    "level": "3",
    "_id": "653d86b99d2e1c46cceb618b",
    "__v": 0
}
```

My Schema:

```
const { Schema, default: mongoose } = require('mongoose')

const writingSchema = new Schema({
  userEmail: String,
  level: String,
  messages: [
    {
      content: String,
      role: String,
      createdAt: Date,
      id: String,
    },
  ],
})

const Writing =
  mongoose.models.Writing || mongoose.model('Writing', writingSchema)

export default Writing
```

My API:

```
import connectMongo from '@/lib/mongodb'
import Writing from '@/models/writing.model'

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  connectMongo().catch((err) =>
    res.status(400).json({ error: 'DB connection error!' }),
  )
  const { userEmail, level, messages } = req.body

  switch (req.method) {
    case 'POST':
      try {
        const newWriting = new Writing({
          userEmail,
          level,
          messages,
        })
        await newWriting.save()
        res.status(201).json(newWriting)
      } catch (error) {
        res
          .status(500)
          .json({ error: 'An error occurred while saving the writing' })
      }
      break
    default:
      res.setHeader('Allow', ['GET', 'POST'])
      res.status(400).json({ error: `Method ${req.method} not allowed!` })
      break
  }
}
```

Comment: In your schema did you mean `createdAt: Date,` instead of `createdAt: Data,`?

Comment: @jQueeny Yes, sorry, misprinted, while creating the question.

Comment: OK cool. I thought that might have been the issue but sounds like it's something else.

Comment: I tested your code locally and it all works fine. I can only assume you have an error in sending your data. Inside your `handler` function can you `console.log(req.body)` as it's likely `messages` is not sent correctly or is misspelled.

Comment: @jQueeny thanks, yes everything was correct I just had to restart the project ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Everything was correct; I just needed to restart the project ‍♂️